# How do I connect to an Access Database through an ODBC DSN using an ASP.Net Data Source?

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, odbc

I have a dsn connection to the database and I have the following command in asp.net to connect to it

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" DSN="tuition" SelectCommand="Select * From [table1]"></asp:AccessDataSource>
```

However the problem is that when using AccessDataSouce we can't use DSN. Is their any other way to get around that( or probably use something else ). As long as Im using DSN Im fine, any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,

Note I have an MS Access Database and Im connecting through odbc

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35c54x95(v=vs.80).aspx

it explains how to connect to an ODBC database using a `SqlDataSource` instead of an `AccessDataSource`.  This method should allow you use your DSN if you specify it in the "server" property:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add 
      name="ODBCDataConnectionString" 
      connectionString="Driver=ODBCDriver;server=tuition;"
      providerName="System.Data.Odbc"
    />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Then change your data source to:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource 
  ID="SqlDataSource1" 
  Runat="server" 
  SelectCommand="Select * From [table1]"
  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ODBCDataConnectionString %>"
  ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ODBCDataConnectionString.ProviderName %>" />
```